# jquery validation does not show error message when user input number

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hello I have this issues with jquery validation plugin. I am trying to allow only letters for my form, it is working but when the user input number it won't show the message that suppose to be "Please provide only alphabets" and it should be under that box.Can anyone help me with this issues?
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/developer-guide/setup#using-zendesk-garden
    https://garden.zendesk.com/css-components/bedrock/
    https://garden.zendesk.com/css-components/utilities/typography/
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/@zendeskgarden/css-bedrock@7.0.21,npm/@zendeskgarden/css-utilities@4.3.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="main.js"></script>-->



    <div id="main" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#main").load("header.html");
            });
        </script>
    </div>

    <style>
        .labels {
            font-size: medium;
            font-family: system-ui;
        }
        
        .required::before {
            content: " *";
            color: red;
            font-size: larger;
        }
        
         ::placeholder {
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-size: small;
            color: #84878b;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="lineContent" style="width:100%;">

        <div class="w3-row">


            <div class="w3-col l10 m7 s4  w3-right">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                    <p><a href="accounts.html">Add Accounttt </a>>> LINE</p>

                </div><br>


                <form name="lineform" id = "line-form" action="main.html" method="POST" onsubmit="insertDB(event,'line')">
                    <div>
                        <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
                        <p class="labels"><input onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" type="text" id="chname" name="chname" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Name" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
                    </div><br>
                    <div>
                        <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
                        <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chid" name="chid" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel ID" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
                    </div><br>
                    <div>
                        <p class="labels required">Channel Access Tokenn:</p>
                        <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chtoken" name="chtoken" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
                    </div><br>



                    <div>
                        <button style="background-color:#1f73b7; color:white; width:8%; height: 35px; border: none; border-radius: 3px;" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div><br>

                </form>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

     <script>



         $.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
             return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
         }, "Please provide only alphabets");

         $('#line-form').validate({

             rules: {
                 chname: {
                     lettersonly: true,

                 }
             },
             messages: {
                 chname: {
                     required: ''
                 }
             },

         });



     

     </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas what is the issue that cause this?
Many thanks.

Comment: You may want to reconsider using an inline JavaScript event handler (`onkeypress`) while also using this jQuery plugin.  The validation is also occurring on the `keyup` event.  Which code do you want?

Comment: Where have you included jQuery itself?

Answer (score 1):

Add script
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
and remove `onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)"` which is overriding it

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my machine and it works fine.

In the case of 'Channel Name', 'onkeypress' is used to block the input of numbers, but if you use paste, you can enter numbers, and the message 'Please provide only alphabets' appears.

In the case of 'Channel Id' or 'Channel Access Tokenn', it appears when you include it in 'rules'.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please provide only alphabets");

$('#line-form').validate({

    rules: {
        chname: {
            lettersonly: true,
        },
        chid: {
            lettersonly: true,
        },
        chtoken: {
            lettersonly: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        chname: {
            required: ''
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script></script>

<div id="lineContent" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div class="w3-col l10 m7 s4 w3-right">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                <p><a href="accounts.html">Add Accounttt </a>>> LINE</p>
            </div><br>

            <form name="lineform" id="line-form" action="main.html" method="POST" onsubmit="insertDB(event,'line')">
                <div>
                    <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
                    <p class="labels"><input type="text" id="chname" name="chname" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Name" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
                </div><br>
                <div>
                    <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
                    <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chid" name="chid" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel ID" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
                </div><br>
                <div>
                    <p class="labels required">Channel Access Tokenn:</p>
                    <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chtoken" name="chtoken" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
                </div><br>
                <div>
                    <button style="background-color:#1f73b7; color:white; width:8%; height: 35px; border: none; border-radius: 3px;" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why in my machine the message does not appears.

Comment: @PanhaSeav I changed it to a snippet. Seems to work on stackoverflow. If there is something else, please tell me

Comment: @PanhaSeav, probably because you're trying to include and use jQuery plugins without first including the jQuery library.